# Passing function to map

Tags: javascript

I was trying to understand this simple code snippet

```
function fnWrapper (fn) {
  return function printResults (...args) {
    const results = args.map(fn)
    console.log(results)
  }
}

const squarePrinter = fnWrapper(x => x*x)
const cubePrinter = fnWrapper(x => x*x*x)
const nums = [1, 2]

squarePrinter(1, 2)
cubePrinter(1, 2)
```

While, almost everything make sense, I am unable to comprehend this part `args.map(fn)`

i.e `map` should give an element but how are we able to pass our fn function and getting the desired result directly

Comment: If it's anything like python, map applies the function to each element of a list and returns list of returns. Or what is the problem?

Comment: `map()` takes function as a parameter, you pass that parameter in another function and use it in `map()` that is wrapped in that function. `fnWrapper(x => x*x)` for example will do this `args.map(x => x*x)`.

Comment: This is commonly called as curry functions [curry function](https://javascript.info/currying-partials)

Answer (score 3):

As per [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) documentation it takes callback function as parameter and returns **A new array with each element being the result of the callback function.**

For example

```
var new_array = arr.map(function callback(currentValue[, index[, array]]) {
    // Return element for new_array
}[, thisArg])
```

So in your case

```
squarePrinter(1, 2)
const results = args.map(fn)
```

is equivalent to

```
const results = [1, 2].map(function(x) {
  return x*x;
})
```

Answer (score 2):

map function takes a callback function, which gets executed with the array elements on each iteration.

You might think of the above code like

```
args.map((x) => x*x);
```

which is nothing but the `fn` function provided as argument to the `fnWrapper`

A typical implementation of map would be something like

```
Array.prototype.map = function (callback) {
    const resultArray = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < this.length; index++) {
        resultArray.push(callback(this[index], index, this));
    }
    return resultArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Map` is a [higher order function](https://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html) which can take callback function as argument, in simple form `map()` implementation would seem like this:

```
Array.prototype.myMap = function(callback) {
    arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
        //Map function take 3 parameter: the item, items's index and the array it self
        arr.push(callback(this[i], i, this));
    return arr;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

args.map(fn) will take each argument and perform the operations on those arguments to create a new list. 
More Like

```
squarePrinter(1, 2) => [1,2].map(x => x*x)
```